# AX2012 AIF X++ class that contains list of classes

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, x++, aif

I have a class with this structure
    class A 
    {
       List Blist;
    }

```
Class B
{
   int i;
}
```

I need my AIF web service operation to accept a single object A that may have multiple instances of B in it. I get an error when i try to deploy the service.

Do i need to explicitly specify AifCollectionTypeAttribute for B in the operation method even though B is contained in A?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `AifCollectionTypeAttribute('return')` and type.

Example:

```
[
    DataMemberAttribute('AttributeValues'),
    AifCollectionTypeAttribute('return', Types::Class, classStr(AttributeValueDC)),
    AifCollectionTypeAttribute('attributeValues', Types::Class, classStr(AttributeValueDC))
]
public List parmAttributeValues(List _attributeValues = attributeValues)
{
    attributeValues = _attributeValues;

    return attributeValues;
}
```